# Decrypt string coded by cryptSync with bash (with the right password)

Tags: bash

After losing my hard drive I try to decrypt data stored in the cloud by cryptSync.
Up to now I correctly recover files and filenames, but I am not able to recover the directory name.

For example, here is one coded directory name `194ef17dcf38a0b3b0eb4f3b6908` I try the following:

```
echo -e 194ef17dcf38a0b3b0eb4f3b6908 | openssl enc $f -a -pass pass:$pass
```

With `$f` all encoding command existing with `openssl` but no one gives me expected result.

What could be the right way of doing that?

Comment: Assuming I've read the code correctly (which is a big assumption) it looks like it is RC4 with an MD5 hash of your password as the key (or something like that).

Comment: Hum this seems interesting, in which file did you find that?

Comment: From [GetDecryptedFilename](https://code.google.com/p/cryptsync/source/browse/trunk/src/FolderSync.cpp#969) and [GetEncryptedFilename](https://code.google.com/p/cryptsync/source/browse/trunk/src/FolderSync.cpp#1100). But like I said I don't know that I was looking at the right place or understanding the code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `-n` so `echo` won't include a newline. Enclose your variables around double-quotes to prevent word splitting as well. I also don't think you need `-e`:

```
echo -n 194ef17dcf38a0b3b0eb4f3b6908 | openssl enc "$f" -a -pass "pass:$pass"
```

Comment: Trying your proposal give me same results (I would say not the decrypted directory name) I'm thinking about some thing with `base64` as the encrypted directory name serve a new directory. I try with `echo -n 194ef17dcf38a0b3b0eb4f3b6908 | openssl enc -base64 | openssl des "$f" -d -pass "pass:$pass"` and result is always `bad magic number`.